# after p:schedule update, it switches to week or month

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I update the p:schedule component, it automatically switches to the "week" or "month" interface.

jsf-version: 2.2.19

primefaces-version:7.0

here is the schedule.

```
 <p:schedule id="adminschedule" value="#{companyCalendarController.eventModel}" extender="includeEndDate" styleClass="value" widgetVar="myadminschedule" </p:schedule>
```

here is the ajax trigger.

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="..." value="#{...}" valueChangeListener="#{...}">
 <p:ajax event="change" update="form:adminschedule"/> </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Comment: It would be really good if you could help yourself first by editing your question and creating a [mcve] and post version. While you are at it, please change the i to I ;-)

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje
Thank you for the reply :-) Is it better now?

Comment: can you copy/paste this in an empty jsf project and run it? And where is your version info? So better, yes, good, no ;-)

Comment: again a little better, but still no [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh a p:schedule without changing the current view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332099/refresh-a-pschedule-without-changing-the-current-view)