# Refresh a p:schedule without changing the current view

Tags: primefaces

I have PrimeFaces 8 with LazyScheduleModel. Can I refresh the current week view, without the schedule to go back to the current date?
Refresh in this component is working, but after refresh, it always goes to the current date, and does not keep the current view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a widget var, and use `PF('scheduleWidgetVarName').update()`. This will update the schedule and keep the current view.

See: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_primefaces.primefaces.widget.schedule-1.html#update